# How do I convert a list of integers into bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some numbers that represent bytes, and I want to make a `bytes` object from them, for example `b"something"`

Here's my attempt, for the record of "making some research". I tried to google it, but found only the other direction (`bytes` to list of numbers). My goal is `b'\x04\x05\x06'` from 4, 5, 6.

The `intelhex` lib is only because that's where I need the `bytes` object.

```
In [1]: from intelhex import IntelHex
In [2]: ih = IntelHex()
In [3]: addr=10
In [4]: a=5
In [5]: b=4
In [6]: c=255

In [7]: ih.puts(addr, bytes(a, b, c))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-def738bb7624> in <module>()
----> 1 ih.puts(addr, bytes(a, b, c))

TypeError: bytes() argument 2 must be str, not int

In [8]: ih.puts(addr, b'{}{}{}'.format(a, b, c))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-eabba8aef324> in <module>()
----> 1 ih.puts(addr, b'{}{}{}'.format(a, b, c))

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'
```

I'm probably doing some stupid mistake here, the `bytes()` function should do it.

Comment: What do you want the bytes to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it, stupid mistake indeed

I was missing brackets there.

```
In [8]: bytes([4,5,6])
Out[8]: b'\x04\x05\x06'
```

Let it help future googlers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `struct` module. See https://docs.python.org/library/struct.html

```
struct.pack(fmt, v1, v2, ...)
Return a string containing the values v1, v2, ... packed according to the given format.
```

Format string info is here: https://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters

So if you wanted each number to be stored as an integer (byte-order is platform-dependent):

```
>>> struct.pack("iii", 5, 4, 255)
b'\x05\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\x00'
```

Or as unsigned bytes:

```
>>> struct.pack("BBB", 5, 4, 255)
b'\x05\x04\xff'
```

Comment: they are integers, but in range 0-255, really just bytes.

Comment: looks good.. weird that it's so complicated for such a simple thing tho

Comment: @MightyPork: it's simple in C because in C characters are "just integers". It's not so simple in Python because in Python characters are "just short strings", so you have to do something extra to get there from an integer.

Comment: nvm, I found how to do it. I needed [] around the bytes. Still good tips, please don't remove it, it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the struct module.

```
In [16]: ret = bytearray(struct.pack("B", a))

In [17]: ret
Out[17]: bytearray(b'\x05')

In [18]: ret.append(b)

In [19]: ret.append(c)

In [20]: ret
Out[20]: bytearray(b'\x05\x04\xff')
```